# how to find a file exists in particular dir through SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

how to find a file exists in particular dir through SSH

for example : 
host1 and dir /home/tree/TEST

Host2:- ssh host1 - find the TEST file exists or not using bash

Comment: do you want to use in application? require boolean or you can simply check with ls command

Comment: yes I want to use this in an application and i need boolean value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ssh will return the exit code of the command you ask it to execute:

```
if ssh host1 stat /home/tree/TEST \> /dev/null 2\>\&1
then 
  echo File exists
else 
  echo Not found
fi
```

You'll need to have key authentication setup of course, so you avoid the password prompt.

Comment: I like to use `test -e` or `test -f` so it becomes: `ssh host1 test -e /home/tree/TEST && echo File exists || echo Not found`.

Comment: ssh host bash -c 'your one-liner shellscript here'

Answer (score 7):

This is what I ended up doing after reading and trying out the stuff here:

```
FileExists=`ssh host "test -e /home/tree/TEST && echo 1 || echo 0"`

if [ ${FileExists} = 0 ]
  #do something because the file doesn't exist
fi
```

More info about test: http://linux.die.net/man/1/test

Answer (score 1):

An extension to Erik's accepted answer.

Here is my bash script for waiting on an external process to upload a file. This will block current script execution indefinitely until the file exists.

Requires key-based SSH access although this could be easily modified to a curl version for checks over HTTP.

This is useful for uploads via external systems that use temporary file names:

- rsync
- transmission (torrent)

Script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -vx

#AUTH="user@server"
AUTH="${1}"
#FILE="/tmp/test.txt"
FILE="${2}"

while (sleep 60); do
    if ssh ${AUTH} stat "${FILE}" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "File found";
        exit 0;
    fi;
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for echo. Can't get much simpler than this :)

```
ssh host "test -e /path/to/file"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    # your file exists
fi
```